# Refreshing a view controller on Firebase logout

Tags: swift, firebase

I have a view controller that has a UICollectionView with information pulled from Firebase. When a user visits this view controller their info is placed in the collection view cells.

However, when the user logs out and logs in with a different account, the previous user's data stays in the collection view rather than re-populating with the new user's info.

Right now everything is called from `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadData()
    loadOngoingQuest()

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
}
```

`loadData()` and `loadOngoingQuest()` pull info from Firebase into arrays used to populate the collection view.

I have tried adding everything in `viewWillAppear()` instead, but it causes some glitches as the collection view involves scrolling and other animations that I don't want to run every time the view controller appears.

Basically I just want to reload the entire view controller every time the user logs out. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of frustration I figured out the issue!

It was nothing to do with refreshing collection views or view controllers. I was using Firebase refs wrong. I had saved two refs in as global constants in a struct in hopes of not having to declare them on every VC. It was like this:

```
struct GlobalConstants {

    struct Refs {
        static let userRef = AppDatabaseReference.users(uid: (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).reference()
        static let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    }

}
```

I would then use them anywhere in my code like this:

```
var questsRef = var questsRef = GlobalConstants.Refs.userRef.reference().child("quests")
```

This would cause issues unless I terminated the app and opened it again, refreshing these variables.

I went back to declaring `let userRef = AppDatabaseReference.users(uid: (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).reference()` at the top in every VC and it solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this, see comments for more info:

```
let firebaseAuth = FIRAuth.auth()
do {
    try firebaseAuth?.signOut()
    // clear the array that your collectionView is based on
    // reload your collectionView (which will clear all the data since your array is empty)
} catch let signOutError as NSError {
    print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
}
```

**Update:**
Another way of handling this:

Create a `Struct` with the following property:

```
struct Global {
    var isNewUser = false
}
```

Whenever you logout a user do this:

```
Global.isNewUser = true
```

And in your `collectionView` you check if `Global.isNewUser == true` then reload everything and most important do set `Global.isNewUser = false`. That way you´ll only load everything once.

Comment: The log out function and arrays don't share the same view controllers

Comment: I mentioned that I tried that solution, but it doesn't work well for my situation as it reloads the data every time the VC appears, running all animations over and over again when I'd rather just load it all once

Comment: @sinio,. added a solution that will suit you better, try it out.

Comment: Thanks! This works to an extent. It refreshes the array and the collection view. However, the old user's info is still loaded when the new user signs in. It only reloads if I terminate then open the app again. There must be something that happens upon `viewDidLoad()` that I'm missing, I've been trying to figure it out for days.

Comment: @sinio, store the user array in the global and do the same thing.

Comment: It didn't work, but I appreciate the help! I will keep trying